# How to find amount of clients in room in socketio

Tags: socket.io

So I am attempting to find the amount of clients connected to a given room at a specific time for the line
`if( rooms[code]!=null && rooms[code].length===2){`
to see if there are 2 people in a given room. From other articles I've seen `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` and the variation `Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms)` are supposed to do this however both always return []. I've also tried `io.sockets.in(roomID).clients` but that always returns undefined. The client definetly joins the room, as sending emits to the room works and looking at the rooms the client is in shows they joined the room. Also as I've tested joining multiple clients, I doubt this is an async issue.

My socketio version is 3.0.1

Code (always goes to else, in else it joins room successfully and inputs are sent just fine):

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on('joinRoom', (code) => {
      let rooms = io.sockets.adapter.rooms;
      if( rooms[code]!=null && rooms[code].length===2){
        console.log("fullroom")
        socket.emit("fullRoom")
      }
      else{
        socket.join(code)
        console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[code]) //undefined
        socket.on('moveEvent', (data)=>{
          io.broadcast.to(code).emit("moveResponse", data)
        })
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` is a map of sets which means to get the size of a specific room is `io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(code).size`. What I had tried to do seems to be what works for earlier versions but not >3.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for joining room is wrong you have to join room like below as shown in documentation [**Joining-and-leaving**](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/#Joining-and-leaving)

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.join('some room');

var room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['my_room'];
room.length;
});
```

This will give you number of joined user or sockets in "my_room"

Comment: Thank you for the response however, I don't see in which way my code is incorrect. Is the problem dynamically entering rooms? It isn't object.keys as it does not work without Object keys either. Can you point out exactly what the issue is?

Comment: Have you checked the link that i have mentioned or you have just downvoted it by seeing code

Comment: I did check the link but didn't see anything that would answer my question there. Also I still am not sure what you mean by my code for joining is wrong.  For the record it wasn't me who down voted you, as I don't even have the reputation to do so. But I would still like clarification on what I did wrong and where in the link I can find my answer.